# Why does this Spectron code block my Electron app after the first click?

Tags: electron, spectron

This is the first time I'm trying to create automated tests for an Electron app using Spectron. It might be my rusty knowledge of async programming but I don't know why the code below is misbehaving:

```
it ('should allow me to create an account', function() {
    return app.client
            .waitUntilWindowLoaded()
            .waitForExist('//a[text()="Create Free Account"]')
            .click('//a[text()="Create Free Account"]')
            .waitForExist('//button[text()="Create Account"]')
            .setValue('#Email', "test@test.com")
            .setValue('#Password', "Password1!")
            .click('//button[text()="Create Account"]')
            .waitForExist('//p[contains(text(),"Almost done.")]')
  });
```

The test seems to get as far as the first click(), then it should wait for the App to request a new page, eventually  displaying a "Create Account" button.  However, for some reason, the app itself seems to block at this point. I know the click is occurring.  When I try it manually, the app behaves properly.

Mark

Comment: Did you sort this out? If not, it might be useful to post a test electron app and the full spectron code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait till the next page loads

Also chain

```
.pause(3*1000)
```

after clicking the button

(Or)

```
.waitUntilWindowLoaded(3*1000)
```